# confusion with empty relations test using 'not exitst'

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm reading database systems concepts by Hank Korth.The book states the following gives list of all students who have taken all courses offered
in the Biology department.

```
select distinct S.ID, S.name
from student as S
where not exists (
        (
            select course id
            from course
            where dept name = 'Biology'
            )           
        except          
        (
            select T.course id
            from takes as T
            where S.ID = T.ID
            )
        );

student(ID, name, dept name, tot cred)
course(course id, title, dept name, credits)
takes(ID, course id, sec id, semester, year, grade)
```

However, to my understanding, the last subquery finds all students who are taking at least one course, and by doing minus from the first subquery, we are subtracting all biology courses that are currently taken by students, so we will be left with biology courses that are NOT taken by any students(if any).Then when we do 'not exists' with all student ID's, we are looking for student ID's who are not taking those found biology courses plus they can take any course other than biology.But that does not give list of students who are taking all courses offered in biology department.Can someone please explain?
Please Note: I do understand the use if 'not exist' from [this](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/exists.php)
site but I'm not getting the book example.

Comment: Please edit your post and **delete** the tags (`mysql`, `oracle`) that don't apply to your question. What database system do you **really** use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are missing is that the NOT EXISTS subquery gets executed independently, for *each* row returned by the outer query.

Notice that its a *correlated* subquery. There's a reference to a column from the outer query `S.ID`.

A single value of `S.ID` is passed in for each execution of the subquery. So, if a student is taking all of the courses from the Biology department, the `EXCEPT` operation in the subquery is going to result in an empty set. And the NOT EXISTS will evaluate to TRUE. But if the subquery returns a row, then there's at least on Biology course which a student isn't taking.